# Do we need a selector for a router-outlet component?

Tags: angular-routing, angular5

Say I have this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And in the router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
  { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '', component: EmptyComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];
```

And the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',  // do we want/need this? Or should I remove?
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

if I go to /about, it should render the about page to the `<router-outlet>` element, so I don't think I need a selector field do I?

Answer (score 3):

If you like you could delete the selector.

But that means that you cannot use `<app-home></app-home>` in any other template.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need selector for routing purpose strictly but may be needed for directives etc. I would keep select though routing-outlet may not use.